# Redirecionar pagina para uma janela modal

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap

Tenho uma página principal, com uma tabela que mostra todas as solicitações que tenho no meu sistema. Cada linha dessa tabela possui um botão, onde abro uma janela modal e nela posso fazer algumas edições.

Ao fazer as edições, salva-las e tal, redireciono a página para a principal(tela da tabela com todas as solicitações) só que aí o usuário teria que procurar qual solicitação ele editou anteriormente.

Queria saber se nesse redirecionamento teria como quando eu redirecionar, ele já abrisse na janela modal que eu acabei de editar. Existe algum meio de fazer isso?

Comment: Não compreendi muito bem, você quer que ... voce redirecionou e tal, e depois salvou, e depois redirecionou de volta, ai nessa volta voce quer que abra o modal informando os dados que voce editou?

Comment: É...na verdade, só haveria um redirecionamento, que seria o redirecionamento depois da edição que irá chamar a pagina inicial, só que o que eu preciso é que quando chamar a pagina principal, já traga com o modal aberto que eu acabei de editar. compreendeu agora?

Comment: pelo o que eu entendi, você terá que ter um modal para visualização (que pode ser o mesmo modal de edição), apenas exibindo as informações que foram cadastradas. Não necessariamente você precisará redirecionar para obter o resultado esperado, principalmente se você estiver utilizando modais (assumindo que o usuário pode fechar o modal e permanecer na pagina que ele estava antes de clicar no ícone de edição). posta seu código ai que creio que fique mais fácil para entendermos. ;)